# How to select element between two immediate elements/tags?

Tags: css

```
<h2>Arbitrary Tag</h2>
<p>no</p>
<p>yes</p>
<p>yes</p>
<p>no</p>
<h2>Arbitrary Tag</h2>
<p>no</p>
<p>yes</p>
<p>no</p>
```

In the above example, how to select paragraph elements that are surrounded with paragraph elements? ("yes" paragraphs in this specific example)

Comment: How do you mean how to select?

Comment: @lolka_bolka since is tagged with CSS .... I guess is how to target with a css selector.

Comment: You can't, there's no way to deselect an element based on its next sibling; this can be done with JavaScript (with, or without, any particular library), but not with CSS.

Comment: There is no CSS selector that will do this for you based on the given structure.

Comment: Target the arbitrary elements instead. We've always done it that way so far.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in CSS.  You could add styles using jQuery to those elements, though.

```js
$('p').each(function(){
  if ($(this).prev('p').length && $(this).next('p').length){
    $(this).addClass('yes');
    }
  });
```

```css
.yes {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Arbitrary Element</h1>
<p>no</p>
<p>yes</p>
<p>yes</p>
<p>no</p>
<h2>Arbitrary Element</h2>
<p>no</p>
<p>yes</p>
<p>no</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

My use case for selecting paragraph elements surrounded by other paragraph elements was to have different margin between the paragraph elements and the surrounding elements. I did this by inverting the role of the elements: instead of trying to target the last of the type element in a row, I have applied the inverse style on the following element.

```css
div,
p { margin: 0; padding: 10px; }
p { background: red; }
p + p { margin: 10px 0; }
p + :not(p) { background: blue; margin-top: 20px; }
:not(p) + p { margin-top: 20px; }
```

```html
<p>I want this to have top margin 20.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have bottom margin 20.</p>
<div>arbitrary element</div>
<p>I want this to have top margin 20.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have bottom margin 20.</p>
<div>arbitrary element</div>
<p>I want this to have top margin 20.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have bottom margin 20.</p>
<div>arbitrary element</div>
<p>I want this to have top margin 20.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have bottom margin 20.</p>
```

Comment: While this answers my specific use case, I will leave the question open until the specific selector support is introduced in the future or someone comes up with a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler variation on your "different margins between paragraphs" answer - using `20px` top/bottom margins on all paragraphs, but reducing that margin *between* paragraphs, for the same effect.

```css
div, p {
  padding: 10px;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  background: red;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

p + p {
  margin-top: -10px;
}

p +:not(p) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>I want this to have top margin 20.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have bottom margin 20.</p>
<div>arbitrary element</div>
<p>I want this to have top margin 20.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have bottom margin 20.</p>
<div>arbitrary element</div>
<p>I want this to have top margin 20.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have bottom margin 20.</p>
<div>arbitrary element</div>
<p>I want this to have top margin 20.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have top margin 10.</p>
<p>I want this to have bottom margin 20.</p>
```

Comment: Negative margin in general should not be used unless there is no other way to achieve the same result, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989930/using-css-negative-margins-a-good-or-bad-practice. This is an opinion, though a community supported for that reason. Adding this variation as a comment on the existing answer would have been enough.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas  I apologize for trying to be helpful in an improper fashion. Please forgive my egregious answer when a simple, humble comment would have sufficed. I'm the worst. Also, if you can point out where any of the potential pitfalls apply in *this* case, that would be informative.

Comment: You are overreacting. I don't like using negative margins because they are not visible in element inspector.

Answer (score -1):

While this isn't possible in CSS I thought I'd offer a plain-JavaScript version of the (multiple) jQuery approaches:

```js
function isSurroundedBy(node, tag) {
  // ensuring that we have a lowercase string to compare with:
  tag = tag.toLowerCase();

  // getting the previous sibling element of the passed-in node:
  var pre = node.previousElementSibling,
    // getting the next sibling element of the passed-in node:
    next = node.nextElementSibling;

  // returns true, if:
  // there is a previous element sibling AND
  return pre &&
    // that element has the correct tagName AND
    pre.tagName.toLowerCase() === tag &&
    // there is a next element sibling AND
     next &&
    // that next element sibling is of the correct tagName:
    next.tagName.toLowerCase() === tag;
}

// using Array.prototype.filter on the array-like nodeList returned by querySelectorAll('p'):
var surrounded = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('p'), function(p) {
  // p, here, is the paragraph-node from the nodeList over which we're iterating:

  // if the isSurroundedBy() function returns true:
  if (isSurroundedBy(p, 'p')) {
    // we return the current <p> element to the filtered array:
    return p;
  }
});

// iterating over the filtered paragraphs, using Array.prototype.forEach():
surrounded.forEach(function(p) {
  // p (again) is the current paragraph-node,
  // setting its color to 'red':
  p.style.color = 'red';
});
```

```html
<h2>Arbitrary Element</h2>

<p>no</p>
<p>yes</p>
<p>yes</p>
<p>no</p>

<h2>Arbitrary Element</h2>

<p>no</p>
<p>yes</p>
<p>no</p>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`Node.nextElementSibling()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling).
- [`Node.previousElementSibling()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode.previousElementSibling).